# Use prototypical inheritance with ES6

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6

How can we use the class keyword in ES6 to add methods on the fly like we did in ES5?

https://jsfiddle.net/user1212/7c57eou3/

```
class Person{
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  getName(){
    return this.name;
  }

  setName(name){
    this.name = name;
  }
}


function Company(cName){
  this.cName = cName;
}

Company.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.cName;
}
```

How can Person have a new method added after the class has been defined?

Comment: In *exactly* the same way as in ES5.

Comment: Like @Bergi said it's the same, it's because classes in Javascript are not a new type, there just decorators for the normal functional prototype.

Comment: What is a use case for adding methods to the prototype after-the-fact?  I can't think of any reason to do that myself when you couldn't just add the methods at the time of class definition.

Comment: @jfriend00 Adding user-defined jQuery methods is an example.

Comment: @Barmar But jQuery doesn't use `class` syntax for its collections, does it?

Comment: @Bergi No, but the reason for adding methods on the fly is unrelated to the syntax used to define the class.

Comment: But, then I don't understand why you would think anything is different with ES6 vs. ES5.    jQuery doesn't even use the `class` keyword and even if it did, all the class keyword does is define a constructor and then populate the `.prototype` object so you just add more items to the prototype just like anything else (no difference in ES5 or ES6).

Comment: Oh, and jQuery has its own scheme for adding methods using `jQuery.fn` which is an alias for a differnet prototype so that's not really a useful example.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use the `class` keyword to add further methods. Just like in ES5, you simply assign them to the prototype object:

```
class Person { … }
…
Object.assign(Person.prototype, { // Object.assign provides a neater syntax
    logName() {                   // but really is the same as Person.prototype.logName = …
        console.log(this.name);
    },
    alertName() {
        alert(this.name);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just don't use `super.foo` props :P

Comment: @loganfsmyth One could even make `super` "work" by using `Object.setPrototypeOf`, but yeah I wouldn't recommend it :-)

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered your specific question, you'd use `prototype`

But just as a reminder, if you are modifying prototype of a `class` to add methods, maybe you want to use `extends` syntax and create a "subclass", so you always use the same class logic without touching prototype.

For most programmers that come from other languages is difficult to understand [`prototype-style` classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming), so if you could use ES6 *only* typical class style, I would say go for it. Like this:

```
class Hello {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  hello() {
    return 'Hello ' + this.name + '!';
  }

  static sayHelloAll() {
    return 'Hello everyone!';
  }
}

class HelloWorld extends Hello {
  constructor() {
    super('World');
  }

  echo() {
    alert(super.hello());
  }
}

var hw = new HelloWorld();
hw.echo();

alert(Hello.sayHelloAll());
```

[taken from here](https://github.com/addyosmani/es6-equivalents-in-es5#classes)

Comment: I would not recommend using JS, let alone `class`es, if you don't understand how prototypes work…